# Help on the end!

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can you **use a end portal on minecraft for 0.13.somthing? It's the newest update? I don't know if you can do it in creative or not ? 
It's confusing and I need help

Comment: What's "0.13-something"? If you want a proper answer, please provide proper details.

Comment: What version are you on? Because PC and PE are quite different in some features.

Comment: Latest release for Pocket / Win10 Edition is 0.13.1. Now that we've guessed which platform you are on, please tell us - what are you trying to do exactly, what have you tried and what seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In minecraft PE, ender portals are function less and can only be accessed in the creative. In other words, there is no end.